# How can I properly set object values inside a promise?

Tags: javascript, object

So I have this object:

```
let user = {
    name: null,
    age: null,
    sex: null,
    created_at: null
}
```

and I want to set the values based on what the promise returns. The data returned has the same property names.

So the promise is this:

```
promise.get(/*url*/).then(res => {
    const data = res.data;
    // set values here
})
```

I have three ways in my mind right now in setting the property values:

```
// First
user = data

// Second
user = {
    name: data.name,
    age: data.age,
    sex: data.sex,
    created_at: data.created_at
}

// Third
Object.assign(user, data);
```

Which is the best/proper way? And what are the advantages of one over the other?
 I'm currently using the Third option. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Option 3 looks fine to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like `Object.assign()`

```js
    const user = {
      name: 'Ronald Mickdonlad',
      age: null,
      sex: 'no thanks',
      created_at: null
    }
    
    const res = {
      data: {
        name: 'Garbo Hamburgler',
        age: 1337,
        sex: '0%',
        created_at: 133713371337
     } 
    }
    
    //fake DB call
    console.log(Object.assign({}, user, res.data))
```

I was trying to show it with spread operator also, but my REPL apparently doesn't have it, so I gave up. See here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

This should work also:

```
return {
  ...user,
  ...res.data
}
```

But, you will need Babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

I prefer both of those over any other way because it is immutable. You are not reassigning any variables. You are doing read-only once assigned and then creating new objects as you go.

Both `Object.assign()` and spread operator have right to left precedence, so "newer aka right-most" values will overwrite "older aka left-occurring" values.

Go with this:

```
const user = {
    name: null,
    age: null,
    sex: null,
    created_at: null
}

// if inside an async function
const updatedUserObj = await promise
  .get(/*url*/)
  .then(res => Object.assign({}, user, res.data))

console.log(updatedUserObj)
```

Here are a couple more examples to show you `Object.assign()` further:

```js
const user = {
    name: null,
    age: null,
    sex: null,
    created_at: null
}

const someObject = {
  coffee: {
    good: true,
    flavour: 'ultra',
    shouldDrink: true,
    age: 1337
  }
}

// Notice how coffee is the property on the object we just created:
console.log('FIRST EXAMPLE', JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, someObject), null, 2))

// Notice how someObject is the property on the new object and coffee is its property
console.log('SECOND EXAMPLE', JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, { someObject }), null, 2))

// Now, watch what happens if we begin overwriting:
console.log('THIRD EXAMPLE', JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, user, someObject), null, 2))

console.log('FOURTH EXAMPLE', JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, { user, someObject }), null, 2))

console.log('FIFTH EXAMPLE', JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, user, { someObject }), null, 2))

console.log('SIXTH EXAMPLE', JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, { user },  someObject), null, 2))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Anyway, may I ask why the assign have 3 parameters with first one as a blank object? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the first parameter of `Object.assign()` is the object you are assigning to, which in most cases will be an empty object, hence `{}`. Then it is a comma separated list of objects that you are assigning into it, with objects to the right overwriting objects to the left. I will include an example above. You would only have something other than `{}` in there if you are mutating an existing object or doing some advanced tactic that would be like this: `Object.assign(Object.create(someObject), obj1, obj2)` which allows you to take prototypes from an existing object.

Comment: I will update my answer with a couple examples and you can click `run` and see what they do.

Comment: My examples there are a bit weak because I didn't really show overwriting. The thing I want you to see is what is happening with `user` and `someObject` in terms of how they get put into the new object as properties or not.

Comment: If you see: `Object.assign({}, { user })`, it is actually shorthand for: `Object.assign({}, { user: user })`. That's where that property comes from.

Comment: Now I know. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 is the better option. In your example with `Object.assign()`, you are using a factory function to create new instance of your `user`. The advantage of this is, it doesn't force you to call a constructor of `user` when you want to create a new `user` instance. You could also use `Object.create()`

This is a basic example of `Object Orientated Programming`.

Read up more here for a better understanding https://www.sitepoint.com/object-oriented-javascript-deep-dive-es6-classes/

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Comment: No problem glad to help :)